# shortcode causing the_content() to return blank?

Tags: shortcode, the-content, options

I have a shortcode that just retrieves some info from the options table in the database.

For whatever reason, when the content reaches a certain character limit the_content() to return blank?

The function is pretty basic and I can't for the life me figure out why this is happening?

Here's an example of the code:

```
function my_custom_shortcode() { return get_option('my_custom_shortcode'); }
add_shortcode('MYSHORTCODE', 'my_custom_shortcode');
```

Has anyone experienced this before? Thanks!

Comment: What is the character limit? That column should be a LONGTEXT data type (http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_options), so the size shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Cole, **please** go back an _work_ (comment/accept/edit question/answer) on your old questions. You're already at a point, where high rep users will step back from answering further questions.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed my problem! I was finally able to find some info out there in the vast internet. Visit this site for info on fixing this odd issue.

Over all using the `remove_filter('the_content','wpautop');` did the trick.

http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/07/sudden-empty-blank-page-for-large-posts-with-wordpress/

Answer (score 1):

In some occasions the_content() will also return blank if a single post/page is viewed and the loop is not initiated. Meaning that you will have to use the code below to be able to see output from the_content.

```
if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
   the_content();
endwhile; endif;
```